# Is there a verbose option for pragma integrity check in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I've been running into an issue lately whereby several applications that utilise SQLite are having corruption issues when the server shuts down. Knowing that it's not a hardware issues, I'd like to get to the root of the problem.

I've taken a snapshot of one of these SQLite databases after corruption occurred, in the hopes that I'll be able to learn something from it.

I ran a pragma_integrity check on the database and all it did was return "Error: database disk image is malformed" - this is exactly what's being output into the application logs.

Is there a verbose mode for this check? I couldn't see anything in the SQLite documentation.

Alternatively is there anything else I could use to analyse the database?

Comment: The PRAGMA should not abort; this bug was fixed recently. Try the latest version.

Comment: When was this fixed - I'm pretty much on the bleeding edge with Fedora Rawhide; I'm on SQLite 3.20.1 ?

Comment: [3.21.0](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_21_0.html)

Comment: So I downloaded the 3.21.0 linux binary from the their website and reran the check. It still aborted.

Comment: Hmm, you corruption appears to be not inside records but in the overall B-tree structure. Anyway, this would not help you find the origin of the corruption; it's likely caused by the server overwriting unrelated parts of the file when shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

`integrity_check` is the verbose form in comparison to `quick_check`, although you can use `integrity_check(n)` to specify the number of errors it returns before completing (default is 100 i.e. without `(n)`).

In your case you only appear to be getting the single error, so using `integrity_check(n)` probably won't make a difference.

[SQLite's - PRAGMA Statements](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check)

Perhaps these links might be of use

- [Repair SQLite Database via SQLite Data Recovery Tool](http://wordpress.semnaitik.com/2017/02/01/repair-sqlite-database/)
- [ERROR: SQLite database is malformed – SOLVED](http://www.froebe.net/blog/2015/05/27/error-sqlite-database-is-malformed-solved/)

Basically they say to try exporting the database using an SQLite tool.

There are loads more if you google `sqlite malformed database`.

You may also find [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)  of interest.